# Getting angular material data table cells to expand to full width of nowrap content?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-material-data-table-overflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) the `mat-cell`s have the width set like this:

```
.mat-cell {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 150rem;
}
```

Without setting the width, the table will crop the text since the `white-space` is set to `nowrap`.  Is there a way to get the `mat-cell` to naturally expand to fit the content without setting a fixed width?

Comment: I have updated the answer pleas ehave a look on it

Answer (score 0):

Use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component and use `ng-deep` in your css

**`app.component.ts`**

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

**`app.component.css`**

```
:host(.mat-cell) {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  min-width: 150px !important;
}
```

Here the working **`stackblitz`**:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-material-data-table-overflow-ymtvr5?file=src/app/app.component.ts**

**Hope this helps :)**

Comment: I clicked on the demo and the lines wrap now.  I think the CSS broke the original CSS.